# Spring MVC with Reactjs fetch error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-mvc

I am getting a similar error from (here)[[Getting "TypeError: failed to fetch" when the request hasn't actually failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343024/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-when-the-request-hasnt-actually-failed?rq=1])

My method is annotated with @CrossOrigin

With postman my request works fine ( from locally)

see POST to http://star-is.info:8080/app-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/register with headers Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded and passing a string with firstname

Locally works fine but my form (here)[http://star-is.info:8082/] does not

```html
       const data = {};
        data['firstname'] = this.state.firstname;
        console.log('submitSignup');
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/app-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json()
        .catch(err => {
            console.err(`'${err}' happened!`);
            return {};
        })).then(function (body) {
            console.log(body);
        })
        .catch(error => {
     alert(error);
  });
```

---

Now I am getting a reply from server

{firstname: null}

but why is firstname not being passed to the server..

The way i achieved this much as using register as endpoint to call in fetch
and using proxy in package.json

---

I removed JSON.stringify with the data and still it is null

See with postman I get the same string back

[image: String sent is returned]

---

I even tried this

```
const data = {'firstname' : this.state.firstname};
```

it is still returned null

Comment: @S.Iqbal please share the error as well.

Comment: Type error failed to fetch..... line1 of my post

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works. I had to encode the data being sent. Is there a better way to do this in Reactjs for more complex objects

```html
const searchParams = Object.keys(data).map((key) => { return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]); }).join('&');
```

And then use searchParams in the body of fetch