# How to avoid net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET uploading files?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to upload PDF files from win10 with primeg p-fileUpload and I getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after 20 sec. I've been uploading files from Win7 and macOS without any problems, PDF files in different sizes like 1M, 5M, 10M.

I am using:
angular: 7
primeng: 7.1
PHP: 7.1
Lumen 5.8

I don't have any logs on the server side.

```
<p-fileUpload [disabled]="!filesForm.valid" [showCancelButton]="false" name="file" chooseLabel="Seleccionar" cancelLabel="Cancelar" uploadLabel="Subir Archivo" [url]="URL" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeUpload($event)" (onError)="onUploadError($event)"
    (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)" [accept]="fileTypes" maxFileSize="maxFileSize" multiple="multiple">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
            <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
        </ul>
    </ng-template>
</p-fileUpload>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [net::ERR\_CONNECTION\_RESET when large file takes longer than a minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736912/neterr-connection-reset-when-large-file-takes-longer-than-a-minute)