# TypeError: Failed to fetch in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am using fetch to post data on backend. Every time, it is success but sometimes it caught error
The data was posted but still error is shown.

I am fetching by code : -
Compose.js

```
fetch(`${props.url}/addBalance`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(obj)
            })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(res =>{
                if(res) alert('Added Successfully');
                else alert('Failed,Try Again');
            }).catch(err=> {console.log(err);alert(err)});
        }
```

The CORS is enabled in backend and working (checked by POSTMAN).

Success:- [Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LICYx.png)
Caught Error :- [without ACAO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZnvI.png)   [with ACAO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Kuj.png)

I run the fetch command in console and it worked fine but not in my React js App

Catch is logging error but still data is being posting

Error:-  TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343024/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-when-the-request-hasnt-actually-failed

Comment: I tried it but failed. I added ACAO in fetch and tried again but not resolved. I have attached error pic with response header with and without ACAO

Comment: Does your backend display any errors?

Comment: No, The data is successfully post in DB. Fro backend I am sending response true if success and false if err

Answer (score 0):

If it was working fine on the server then the problem could be with the response headers. Check the Access-Control-Allow-Origin (ACAO) in the response headers. Usually react's fetch API will throw fail to fetch even after receiving response when the response headers' ACAO and the origin of request won't match.

Comment: I had tried both, with ACAO and without it too. I attached error pic of both showing response header.

Answer (score 0):

Add **Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin** extension to your chrome or browser then enable it and check the reponse after that

Comment: I enabled and tested. It passed but issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

I was using Form to take the input from user due to which before fetching, page was reloaded and it showed 'failed to Fetch' and status was shown "Cancelled" in Chrome developer tools.
To fix this I used Div tag.