# i have this error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, blogger

I am sorry if I asking alot but i need help.
I used this script it is worked ok but in console i have this error :{Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch}
can any one to tell me where is my mistake.

```
fetch('/feeds/posts/default?alt=json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  var authorPosts = data.feed.entry.filter(e => e.author[0].name.$t === "mark wael");
  var len=authorPosts.length;
  console.log(len);
  $(".authorPostsCount").append(len);
});
------------------
<span class='authorPostsCount'/>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343024/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-when-the-request-hasnt-actually-failed) could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way you are using fetch is not correct! fetch is used for an HTTP request, so u need to specify the URL as a parameter I think.

check the link on the MDN website  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: but its worked ok i have get a valid response. But also getting this error at the same time.