# Getting Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am passing user input data from React js to node js i.e backend, by using **fetch api** and successfully storing the data to my database. But **fetch api** is not returning the object successfully and always showing me **window.alert('Registration failed')** and showing the following error in console. I tried every solution but not working.

**Error Screenshot**
[image]

**CustomerRegistration.jsx**

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
        
        const { fname, lname, email, password, address } = state;

        try {
            res = await fetch('/customer-registration', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, password: password, address: address
                })
            })

            const data =  res.json();
            console.log(`my data ${data}`);

            if (data) {
                window.alert('Customer registered successfully');
            }

        } catch (error) {
            window.alert('Registration failed');
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share the error code at least... Open chome devtools, go to network, share header request and response

Comment: It could be CORS issue, please check the console errors too.

Answer (score 1):

.json() method returns a Promise, you need to wait until it finishes to get the data. Change the line :

```
  const data =  res.json();
```

to :

```
  const data =  await res.json();
```

See the document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

About the error "Failed to fetch", if the backend is working fine, then it could be a CORS issue. You may need to enable CORS in the backend part, check this thread: [Getting "TypeError: failed to fetch" when the request hasn't actually failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343024/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-when-the-request-hasnt-actually-failed)

Comment: Thanks to correct but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

One question: Does your api convert JSON String into Javascript Object?

If not you should not stringify the Javascript Object on the body.

Comment: Also please don't ask questions in answers - use comments for that