# How to get data in react with API fetch call

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, fetch-api

Basically I am trying to find a way how the fetch data works. I have created a method that returns a simple list and the response of the body is as follow:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "ApooBG",
    "Password": "e062f192A",
    "Email": "idk@abv.bg"
  },
  {
    "Name": "VenszBG",
    "Password": "12645",
    "Email": "idkk2@abv.bg"
  },
  {
    "Name": "PetarGH",
    "Password": "1245",
    "Email": "idkk3@abv.bg"
  }
]
```

then I have in react a button that calls a method, where it should get this list.

```
<div> <button onClick={Testing}>Edit Info</button></div>
```

```
    const Testing = () => {
        fetch("https://localhost:7101/GetUsers")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    };
```

When I try to click on the button I need to get the users in the console.log but instead I get:

[image: this error]

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong as I really don't get the idea. The URL should be okay as this is what the request URL is. Therefore, the problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: You have an unhandled rejection, maybe on the back end, maybe on the front end.

You could add `.catch((error) => { console.log(error); })` after the last `.then()` and see what that says, might help you diagnose it a little bit

Comment: Do you get the correct response when you just visit your API URL in another tab?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct response. And here is the error that I get: https://pastebin.com/8iGG46qB

Comment: Look at your devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just check the log. `TypeError: Failed to fetch` might occurs when the API Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) errors happen. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895164/10766263

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help, how about testing with dummy API first available online? Here one of open API example that can be used:

```js
const Example = ({title}) => {
    
    const Testing = () => {
        fetch("https://dummyjson.com/users/1")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    };
  
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <button onClick={Testing}> Edit Info</button>
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example:" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If this work, try to check your backend port and proxy setting. Maybe this one will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022

Comment: Yes, it does get the information in the console. Basically, the problem is in the backend. Unfortunately, I don't understand where, is it the CORS error or something else? The mentioned link doesn't help me much as I am really lost somewhere in between

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0 sorry for late response. You can check this out @Venoz